# Get all from table AND sort?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

Using the following code in my controller, I am able to retrieve all rows from my table, but it won't sort by the column `last_name`. Any suggestions?

```
 @pi_names = PiName.all(:order => 'pi_names.last_name DESC')
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try

```
 @pi_names = PiName.order('pi_names.last_name DESC').all
```

Comment: Yes it worked! I was getting confused because i did DESC instead of ASC

Answer (score 3):

Alternative syntax allowing any errors to potentially be caught prior to runtime:

```
@pi_names = PiName.order(last_name: :desc)
```